# How to make react native Deep linking clickable

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I am making an invite-only app and when the user gets the link it's not clickable the link looks like this app://invite-link/id/id. How can I make this link clickable?

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on how you're actually displaying the link. Is it a simple `<Text>`? If it is, you could do something like this:

```
const URL = "app://invite-link/id/id";

<Text onPress={() => Linking.openURL(URL)}>
  {URL}
</Text>
```

Linking docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking

Comment: I think you didn't understand, I am getting the link in the mobile message how can I click on it.

Comment: I think i need universal link with https so I can click on it.